# java.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [java.lang.comparable]

Tags: java

I'm stuck at this `java.lang.ClassException`. In general, I'm trying with a simple method `maxElement()` that simply returns the highest Integer, the `add()` method works perfectly as well as overriding `toString()`, this last 2 methods are inherited from `ArrayLinearList<T>`. **element** is               an array .   **ArrayLinearList** does work perfectly as well .This is my code:

```
public class ArrayLinearList<T> implements LinearList<T>, Iterable<T>{
 protected T[] element; 
 protected int size; 
  *constructors and methods*
  // default constructor makes an T[]element of length 10
```

}

```
public class ArrayLinearListTaller1<T extends  Comparable<T>> extends ArrayLinearList<T>{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayLinearListTaller1<Integer>x=new ArrayLinearListTaller1<Integer>();
    x.add(0, new Integer(10));
    x.add(1, new Integer(5));
    x.add(2, new Integer(7));
    System.out.println(x);
    System.out.println(x.maxElement());
    }// end of main

 public T maxElement() {
    Arrays.sort(element,0,size);
    T max= element[size-1];//*error here*
    return max;
}
```

This is what I get:

```
[10,5,7]  
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Comparable;
```

Comment: What does element refer to? Please provide relevant details of your ArrayLinearList class as well

Comment: please show the declaration and initialization of element array

Comment: -1 for not including the declaration and initialization of `element`.

Comment: And a vote to close for not including the exception stack trace.

Comment: (The error did not occur on the line you indicate.  It likely occurred on the `sort` call.)

Answer (score 2):

The elements passed to [Arrays.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20int,%20int)) must implement [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface.

> Sorts the specified range of the specified array of objects into
> ascending order, according to the natural ordering of its elements.
> The range to be sorted extends from index fromIndex, inclusive, to
> index toIndex, exclusive. (If fromIndex==toIndex, the range to be
> sorted is empty.)
>
> All elements in this range must implement the
> Comparable interface.
>
> Furthermore, all elements in this range must be
> mutually comparable (that is, e1.compareTo(e2) must not throw a
> ClassCastException for any elements e1 and e2 in the array).

So the Objects present in `element` array **must implement `Comparable` interface**.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like whatever your type of object for element is does not implement Comparable interface and you're getting exception from Arrays.sort(). Maybe sharing your full code will help.